# Create custom meta tag with the metatag module

Tags: meta-tags

Just this. I need to create some metatag using the metatag module: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Something like:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

I can't see how to get this in its setting.

Then after I will need to use these metatags in nodes and views.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [Custom Meta](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_meta) module or roll your own module:

From Custom Meta project page:

> The module allows you to define and manage custom meta tags. Simply
>   select the Meta attribute (property, name, http-equiv) and set the
>   value and content value in the format and the module will add your
>   meta tags to all non-admin content for your site.

An example of writing your own module:

**my_metatag.info**

```
name = My Metatags  
description = Provides my custom Metatags.  
core = 7.x  
version = 7.x-1.x  
dependencies[] = metatag  
files[] = my_metatags.metatag.inc
```

**my_metatag.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 */
function my_metatags_ctools_plugin_api($owner, $api) {
  if ($owner == 'metatag' && $api == 'metatag') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

**my_metatag.metatag.inc**

```
<?php
//
// Implements hook_metatag_info().
//
function my_metatags_metatag_info() {
  $info['groups']['my_metatags'] = array(
    'label' => t('My Custom Metatags'),
  );

  $info['tags']['my_custom_metatag'] = array(
    'label' => t('My Custom Meta Tag'),
    'description' => t('This is a custom meta tag'),
    'class' => 'DrupalTextMetaTag',
    'group' => 'my_metatags',
  );

  return $info;
}

//
// Implements hook_metatag_config_default_alter().
//
function my_metatags_metatag_config_default_alter(array &$configs) {
  foreach ($configs as &$config) {
    switch ($config->instance) {
      case 'global':
        $config->config += array();
        break;

      case 'global:frontpage':
        $config->config += array();
        break;

      case 'node':
        $config->config += array(
          'my_custom_metatag' => array('value' => 'This is a default value.'),
        );
        break;

      case 'taxonomy_term':
        $config->config += array();
        break;

      case 'user':
        $config->config += array( );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can see some other ways to add metatags on another question "[How do I add a meta tag in inside the <head> tag?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-inside-the-head-tag)" like through a template or a theme.