# How do I add a meta tag inside the <head> tag?

Tags: meta-tags

How can I add the following meta tag inside the `<head>` tag?

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I am trying to add it to a Drupal 8 site.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From different sources I found different way of adding meta tags in Drupal 8, hence compiling all ways.

#### Using a THEME.theme file

The same question has been asked on [Add meta tag to `<head>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913739/add-meta-tag-to-head). [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35939040/225647) provides the following code.

Just add the following code in the *.theme* file, and clear the cache.
The `theme_preprocess_html()` function should be already there in the *.theme* file; don't add another function with the same same, or PHP will throw an error.

```php
function theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $xuacompatible = [
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => [
      'http-equiv' => 'x-ua-compatible',
      'content' => 'ie=edge',
    ],
  ];

  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$xuacompatible, 'x-ua-compatible'];
}
```

#### Through a template file

In [How can I set/remove meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530066/how-can-i-set-remove-meta-tags), the user who asked the question mentioned that it's possible to add meta tags in the *html.html.twig* file. The template file used by Drupal core is *core/modules/sytem/templates/html.html.twig*. You can copy and paste its content in a theme's template folder.

The relevant part in that template file is the following one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes }}>
    {#
      Keyboard navigation/accessibility link to main content section in
      page.html.twig.
    #}
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Create your own custom module

If you follow [Adding new HTML tags in the `<head>` in Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/adding-new-html-tags-drupal-8), it describes the general way of adding tag to head in Drupal 8. I have modified the code to adapt it to the question you asked.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function module_name_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $xuacompatible = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'http-equiv' => 'x-ua-compatible',
          'content' => 'ie=edge',
        ],
      ];
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$xuacompatible, 'x-ua-compatible'];
}
```

#### Using a Drupal module

You can use the *Metatag* module for this, which requires the *Token* and the *Chaos Tool Suite (ctools)* modules.

Answer (score 8):

When adding content to a controller, block, entity, field or other places you don't need to create a hook.

You can attach the meta tag directly to a render/build array. Any render array has at least one render child (containing `#theme`, `#type`, `#markup`, `#plain_text`), where you can place the attachment:

```
$build['username'] = [
  '#theme' => 'username',
  '#account' => \Drupal::currentUser(),
  '#attached' => [
    'html_head' => [
      [
        [
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => [
            'name' => 'foo',
            'content' => 'bar',
          ],
        ],
        'my_module_foo',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

When rendered the tag bubbles up to page level and is added to the `<head>...</head>` section.

In a preprocess hook you can attach to the top level of `$variables`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288989/47547

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Meta](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_meta) module is the way to go. It has a very straightforward configuration and allows adding any custom meta tag to the page head section.

> The module allows you to define and manage custom meta tags. Simply select the Meta attribute (property, name, http-equiv) and set the value and content value in the format and the module will add your meta tags to all non-admin content for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use the Metatag module.

We need to enable Metatag: Mobile & UI Adjustments submodule.

After doing this from metatag config page we would be able to see Windows & Windows Mobile under each metatag type and according to our requirement, we can add either globally or page-specific X-UA-Compatible content.

Answer (score 0):

### Drupal 7 answer

Recently had to implement some Open Graph `<meta property="og:xxx" content="xxx">` tags for Facebook embedding. 
Drupal 7 let's you also do the following (not sure about Drupal 8 though):

```
$ogTitleElement = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta', // The #tag is the html tag -
    '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
        'property' => 'og:title',
        'content' => 'My Custom Title',
    ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($ogTitleElement, 'facebook_title');
```

Code can be added inside your custom module, or inside the `<themename>_preprocess_html` function of your theme's `template.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module can be used to set title and meta tags for the front page and a description meta tag for the node page.

### Set title and meta tags for the front page.

Install and enable the Mix module.
Goto /admin/config/mix, find and click the Meta tags link or goto /admin/config/mix/meta directly.
Fill the Frontpage form then click Save Configuration
Goto front page and inspect the page title and source code to see all the changes.
[image: Mix frontpage meta tags settings form]
[image: Mix Meta tag - Frontpage source code]

### Set a description meta tag for the node page.

Install and enable the Mix module.
Goto /admin/config/mix, find and click the Meta tags link or goto /admin/config/mix/meta directly.
Fill the Node form then click Save Configuration
Goto any node page and inspect the source code to see the changes.
[image: Mix node meta tag form]