# How can I add an unescaped script tag and contents to a page?

Tags: 8

I would like to add to my pages the structured data in JSON-LD (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)

Basically, what I need to do is to add somewhere in the HTML for, let's say a basic page, a snippet like the following:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{  "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"WebSite",
   "name":"Site name",
   "alternateName":"Site alternatime name",
   "description":"Site description",
   "keywords":"list of keyword",
   "inLanguage":"en",
   "url":"http://www.example.eu/en",
   "potentialAction":{
   "@type":"SearchAction",
   "target":"http://www.example.com/en/find/{search_term_string}",
   "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script>
```

I've tried to use the full HTML input but the snippet gets (kind of) escaped with the CDATA and google cannot parse it.

So, how can I provide that snippet without any escaping?

Comment: Are you aware that Drupal 8 comes with RDFa (which is an alternative to JSON-LD) support? See e.g. [rdfui](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Do you have a more specific question which is not _Do you have any suggestions?_ This site is not for suggestions, but to answer well-defined questions with a definitive answer.

Comment: My specific question is: I need to add to the HTML of the page (let's say basic page) the snippet provided above. I've tried to use the full HTML input but the snippet gets (kind of) escaped with the CDATA and google cannot parse it. So, how can I provide that snippet without any escaping?

Comment: I think that in some way RDFa is an old way of providing semantic metadata about a website and it will be replaced by JSON-LD structured data. Now google is pushing for JSON-LD as you can see here: developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-da‌​ta.

Comment: Does anyone have any answer fot this question?

Comment: There is a sandbox module for D8 [JSON-LD (D8 core)](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/linclark/1802036). Since it's a sandbox project, it is not advisable to use it in production because it is not properly tested. But you can have a look at it and try in local if it works. You can download the module code from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/1802036/git-instructions). If you're interested to work on it, you can also ask the module owner to add you as maintainer so you can continue work and make the module complete and stable.

Comment: @user3535189 Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I've edited your comment into the question and broadened the scope a bit so the title doesn't focus so much on the specifics of the tag you're trying to inject...if you can entice Drupal into rendering _any_ unescaped script then you've succeeded and people are already focusing on the JSON-LD specifically, which is great if there's a solution there, but it's potentially limiting the options people are likely to suggest. If I've changed your intentions please feel free to revert/revise

Comment: There is an actively maintained module on GitHub named [claw-jsonld](https://github.com/Islandora-CLAW/claw-jsonld). It depends on the following Drupal 8 core modules: rest, serialization and rdf. They hold weekly meetings, the following being [tomorrow](https://github.com/Islandora-CLAW/CLAW/wiki/February-1%2C-2017), so you can get in touch with them if you don't find your way around the different services provided.

Comment: Hi @user3535189, I posted an aswer with detailed instructions. One question though: does the `<script>` tag need to be in the `<head>` tag or can it also be in the `<body>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this with no additional modules required. For the sake of this example, I'm going to add this field to the `Basic page` content type that comes with the `Standard` installation profile.

First, let's create a new Text format. Go to `admin/config/content/formats` and click `Add text format`. I name the Text format **JSON-LD** and make it only available for Administrators. Be sure to leave all options blank and set `Text editor` to `None`, like so:

[image: Step 1]

Then, let's add a new field to the `Basic page` content type. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/add-field` and select `Text (formatted, long)`. I name the field **JSON-LD** with an automatic machine name of `field_json_ld`.

[image: Step 2]

Then let's make sure we hide the field's label. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display` and make sure to set the Label to our new **JSON-LD** field to `- Hidden -`, like so:

[image: Step 3]

Now it's time to add the script to a new page. Go to `node/add/page` and fill in the Title and Body as you like. Here's the important bit: for the **JSON-LD** textarea, be sure to set the `Text format` to **JSON-LD**, like so:

[image: Step 4]

Now click `Save and publish`. Your node will look like this:

[image: Step 5]

Nothing special, right? Now let's take a look at our source code:

[image: Step 6]

Bingo!

Comment: Hi, I am somewhat confuse here, first lets understand what is the purpose of this script. From its content it and from JSON-LD words, it looks like it has to be detected by Search engine boats. Hence, it has to be present in <head></head> section of the site. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @CodeNext: yes it should be inside the head tag. But I noticed that Google is reading it even if it is placed in the body. Is there a way to insert some custom HTML in the head tag?

Comment: @user3535189 If you need the way to add that part, please see my answer [HERE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-head-head-section-in-d8/217882#217882), I have compiled all ways to add code in <head></head>, I hope it will help.

Comment: @CodeNext thank you for your suggestion, it is good for something like a meta tag for the whole website. But i was searching tomething more clever, I mean, if I have 20 pages, each page should have a different "JSON-LD" snippet. So I'll probably need a text field like the one explained by Wim, that is then placed in the "head2 instead of the "body" tag.

Comment: @user3535189, Hhmmm, in that case this is appropriate way. Please after testing in your live site let me know, if google is identifying this way this snippet. I need to reward bounty to this answer, if you are accepting as a answer. Thx

Comment: I think that the correct answer till now is Wim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default Full HTML format uses CKEditor, which performs it's own text filtering and is likely what is causing your problems. You can disable CKEditor's Advanced Content Filter, but what I would recommend is creating a new text format with no filtering and no text editor. Then create a new long text field for your page's content type, and set the new text format as default.

You should be able to paste whatever scripts you need in the new field.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add the script to the editor, use the PHP code filter instead of full HTML, then add your snippet. It will work fine.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: This could be a way, but I think that Wim's answer is better.

Comment: Yes Sure, but in this way there is no need to add the new text format.