# From Controller to html.twig

Tags: 8

I have a module that define a Routing and a controller

```
my.partner:
  path: '/partner/{alias}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\myname\Controller\PagesController::partner'
    _title: 'Partner'
```

In controller I define the template to use:

```
$variables = [
         '#theme' => 'page_partner',
]....
```

But I need to pass some "variables" from this "controller" to html <head>. How can I do it ?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-head-head-section: add an `html_head` attachment to the render array containing the tag that you want to appear in `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

Define the variables in your theme and the pass them as "#variable" = value. E.g. in YOUR_MODULE.module have something like:

```
function tb_megamenu_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items['tb_megamenu'] = [
  'template' => 'tb-megamenu',
    'variables' => [
      'menu_name' => NULL,
      'content' => NULL,
      'section' => 'frontend',
      'block_theme' => \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default'),
    ],
  ];
}
```

In your controller use:

```
$render = [
  '#theme' => 'tb_megamenu',
  '#menu_name' => $this->getMenuName(),
  '#block_theme' => $this->getThemeName(),
  '#content' => $this->getContent(),
];
```

Comment: Sorry.. did not see the Head requirement.  Clive is right.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bumped up to the homepage. To make the [comment of @Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246688/from-controller-to-html-twig#comment302143_246688) more clear, you can attach page attachments via `#attached` to any theme or render element (`#theme`, `#type`, `#markup`) and it will bubble up to page level when rendered:

```
$variables = [
  '#theme' => 'page_partner',
  '#attached' => [
    'html_head' => [
      [
        [
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => [
            'name' => 'foo',
            'content' => 'bar',
          ],
        ],
        'my_module_foo',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```