# Generate meta in controller

Tags: 8, meta-tags, page-controller

I'm creating a custom module. This module displays public custom content without node and views . For this content custom page , I would like to add dynamic meta keyword and meta description .

I have read this excellent answer
[How do I add a meta tag in <head>...</head> section?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-head-head-section/217882#217882)
and it said we can use

```
mymodulename_page_attachments(&$page)
```

and update variable

```
$page
```

But the meta contents are getting in a controller's method. For this raison, I would like to 
pass the meta contents to `mymodulename_page_attachments` hook.

How can I call and update `$page` in my controller module to do this ? Or how can I generate meta in my controller ?

Comment: Move the logic into a service then use the service in both contexts (controller and hook). You can statically cache the results of the op if it’s expensive. Or maybe try attaching html_head to the render array you return from the controller and see if it bubbles up to the page layer (something tells me it will but I’m not sure)

Comment: tank's I didn't think to this. I will try .

Comment: @Clive than'ks . Your message told me what to do and what to learnt . ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service was the key to my problem .

After i understood Drupal services
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8

and

http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-define-your-own-services-drupal-8

It's easy to define dynamic keyword and meta to one page

```
function mymodulename_page_attachments(array &$page) {
    $currentUrl = Drupal::request()->get(Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME); 
    switch($currentUrl){
        case 'path_url': 
        //call my service 
          $description = array(
                '#tag' => 'meta',
                '#attributes' => array(
                    'property' => 'description',
                    'content' => /* value to my service return */,
                ),
            );

            $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$description, 'description'];
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hook_page_attachments() is only needed so you can attach it to any possible route/url. You should be to just add it directly to the response that you re returning, and it should bubble up and be added.

Comment: thank's to your response . I didn't understood realy what was Drupal Service. It's mistake . :-)