# Injecting metadata into all nodes within one folder

Tags: 8

For my school I need to add metadata into the  tag of every node/page within the folder /course/

The metadata is the same for every page in this folder:

```
<meta class="swiftype" name="tags" data-type="string" content="course" />
```

This will allow me to use weighting for all our course pages in the Swiftype search app.

I've narrowed it down to the html.html.twig file in \core\modules\system\templates - where I believe I need to be adding something along the lines of:

```
if (preg_match('$^course/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']])) { print_metatag }
```

But I won't be wanting to use print_metatag. Instead I should be using the fixed metadata referenced above.

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to use, and where, to apply this metadata to all those /course/ nodes/pages.

Many thanks!

Comment: First of all you can change `\core\modules\system\templates\html.html.twig` it's core template you should override it in your custom module or theme  second thing this is `if (preg_match('$^course/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']])) { print_metatag }` php can't be in twig.
Did you use metatags module ?

Comment: Welcome Dave  would all of these be one content type that is only used in this place? or do you need to be doing it by path?

Comment: @NickWilde it's for just one content type - called Instance. Every node of the Instance content type.

Comment: The simplest way would be to add the metatag in a node preprocess hook, then you don't need to check for a path or route parameters. The metadata will then bubble up on each page where the content type is displayed, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283609/47547

Comment: @4k4 this is an intriguing idea. Would the idea be to simply customise the code in the link you shared, and append it to the node.module file as per https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x

Comment: Yes, always try to attach things like metatags or libraries to the content they depend on. If you keep things together you can maintain the code much better. Also Drupal caching is most efficient this way.

Comment: @4k4 I've been trying everything to make your solution work.

When in your link you said:

You can add the meta tag directly to any theme or render element (#theme, #type, #markup):

are you saying add that code to node.module in core/modules/node?

And if so, does it matter where that code is added?

And if I wanted it to solely append the <meta> to the instance content type, should I change line 2 from

'#theme' => 'username',

to

'#type' => 'instance',

And does anything else from that script need to be changed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I've added an answer with a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use PHP like that in Twig, but your logic isn't far off. One of the reasons Drupal 8 switched to using Twig was to avoid having potentially unsafe PHP in template files – this sort of thing generally belongs in a module rather than in a template, especially as it's not related to the presentation of content.

Drupal doesn't have a concept of folders, but we can look at the path of the content (e.g. `/courses/drupal-development` or `/contact-us` or `/news/2018/cool-thing-that-happened`) and work out if it's 'under' courses or not that way.

Something like this *should* work, but is untested:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $exploded_path = explode('/', $current_path);

  // Add Swiftype metatag, see https://swiftype.com/documentation/site-search/crawler-configuration/meta-tags.
  if ($exploded_path[1] === 'courses') {
    $metatag = [
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => [
        'name' => 'tags',
        'data-type' => 'course',
        'class' => 'swiftype',
        'content' => 'course',
      ],
    ];

    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$metatag, 'swiftype_course'];
  }
}
```

Or to do it by content type:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if ($node->getType() === 'instance') {
      $metatag = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'name' => 'tags',
          'data-type' => 'course',
          'class' => 'swiftype',
          'content' => 'course',
        ],
      ];

      $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$metatag, 'swiftype_course'];
    }
  }
}
```

If you need help setting up a module then take a look at https://befused.com/drupal/first-drupal8-module - but you can stop once you've created a `your_module_name.module` file – this is the file that the code above will go into.

Comment: CTI, eh? Always the cream of the crop. Phil - you are an absolute legend for attempting this! Thanks so much. Will give it a shot this weekend and see what occurs. I'm XAMPPed up so no damage will be done either way. Keep you updated; thanks so much for taking time out of your Friday night to help.

Comment: Hey @DaveThackeray, I saw Paul's bat-signal and thought I might be able to help out! I've just updated my answer having seen your comment that this is to be applied by content type really, rather than path. Doing it by content type makes things a lot more robust and cleaner feeling, as changing the URL structure won't now break functionality.

Comment: Do note that
```
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    if ($node->getType() === 'instance') {
```
is a bit risky, better to do:
```
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    if (is_obj($node) && $node->getType() === 'instance') {
```
Since on some routes (ie node revisions, the node parameter doesn't get upcasted and hence is an int).

Comment: Ah, good point – this is why I'm primarily a frontender! It looks like that issue isn't fixed yet (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2730631) so I'll edit my answer to incorporate @NickWilde's suggestion.

Comment: I used a check for `$node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface` instead of `is_object()`, but I think both approaches would prevent the problem that Nick described – thanks for the suggestion! 

Answer (score 2):

The [answer linked in the comments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283609/47547) is for a render array you build yourself. If you want to attach something to an existing render array you would need to look for a render element  (#theme, #type, #markup) you can attach it to. You could look for such a render element in $variables, but a preprocess hook is an exception to this rule. Here the (only) officially supported method of attaching bubbleable metadata (#cache, #attached) is the top level of $variables, even if there is no render element. Drupal looks for such metadata and bubbles it up.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['node']->getType() == 'article' && $variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {

    $metatag = [
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => [
        'name' => 'tags',
        'data-type' => 'course',
        'class' => 'swiftype',
        'content' => 'course',
      ],
    ];

    $variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$metatag, 'swiftype_course'];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are three methods really.

1. I won't go over, since it is what Phil said
2. Create a custom module extending metatag. This is in many way ideal, but is the most complicated method. Given your stated experience level, this is likely a challenge, and probably not worth it for such a static option.
3. Use the html template you identified. For this just copy `core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig` to `%your_theme/templates/layout/` as `html--node--instance.html.twig`. Or if you you already have an `html.html.twig` in yuor theme, copy that to the new name. Then add your metatag directly into the new template.

Do note that any of those three options will require you to clear caches or they won't take effect.