# Is it possible to alter html_head using hook_page_attachments_alter() per node?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to alter html_head using `hook_page_attachments_alter()` per node? I need to attach different `<script>` tags to a list of nodes. I am able to add it to each node, but all gets overridden with the last alteration.

```php
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'faq_page', 'status' => 1]);

foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $description = [
    [
      '#tag' => 'script',
    ],
    // …
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$description, 'description];
}
```

Comment: What is the list of nodes? And how is it connected to the page content, an entity route of a single node?

Comment: How the hook works in general and what else might be helpful especially in this case for multiple nodes see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288826/injecting-metadata-into-all-nodes-within-one-folder

Comment: @4k4 that is great point that I forgot to include. I'll update the post with that information, but it is $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'faq_page', 'status' => 1]);

Comment: Are those nodes also part of the page? Then it might be a better idea to add the attachments to the rendered nodes itself instead of querying the nodes again.

Comment: @4k4 To give you more context, the value of the script is json-ld data generated from a service file. The code you see is part of .module file. I'm using this to append that <script type="application/ld+json">...</script> to head of corresponding node.

Comment: My argumentation is that the attachments then belong in the corresponding node as discussed in the linked topic. The connection I asked about is still unclear, but it doesn't really matter. Everyone who is reading this should try to avoid using this hook and attach metadata to render elements, #cache + #attached, they both work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you get the current node.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {

    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      [
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#value' => 'alert("' . $node->getTitle() . '")',
      ],
      'MYMODULE_foobar',
    ];
  }
}
```

---

If this really should be in a `foreach`, you need to ensure to give each tag an unique key.

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $description = [
    [
      '#tag' => 'script',
    ],
    ...
  ];
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$description, 'description_' . $node->id()];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work with your help :)

Comment: How would I make that script attach to that node only? With the current structure, scripts get attached to all nodes in that array.

Comment: @PhilipPark – Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Maybe have some if-requests checking for the node ID, node type or something like that before you enter the logic?

Comment: @PhilipPark – At best you have a Views block querying the nodes you want, place that block somewhere on the page and build the schema.org markup directly there in that block template. It doesn't necessarily have to be in the head right? But even if, hook into the View and attach the head script from there then.