# How can I add inline JavaScript on a page returned from a custom controller (not with a library)?

Tags: javascript, 9, page-controller

How can I add another render element that contains my custom JavaScript code?

Do I use `['#attached']['html_head']` or code similar to the following one?

```php
$build['body']['script'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => "<script>window.alert('hello world')</script>",
];
```

Comment: Any reason why a library can't be used? According [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2391025) the support of inline js has been removed at sometime and currently isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to alter html\_head using hook\_page\_attachments\_alter() per node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/301098/is-it-possible-to-alter-html-head-using-hook-page-attachments-alter-per-node)

Comment: The fastest way is described in this article: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-add-real-inline-javascript-drupal-8-page-or-module