# Javascript library with "modulepreload"

Tags: javascript, 10

Lately working with [svelte](https://svelte.dev/) in a project. The generated HTML uses Javascript with link and [modulepreload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/modulepreload):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/entry/start.ed2a2ab5.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/scheduler.8a566589.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/singletons.a436eea2.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/index.220c2c81.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/entry/app.e682a49a.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/index.95a0b3d5.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/nodes/0.77b736d5.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/nodes/2.87586eb9.js">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        // some scripts here to use the preloaded module code.
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I declare in `mymodule.libraries.yml` so files can be displayed as this link format?

Comment: Libraries don't support arbitrary tags, just stylesheets and scripts. It's extendable if you're so inclined, but it may be (quite a bit) easier to use `hook_page_attachments_alter()` and add `html_head` items instead, e.g. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/301098/is-it-possible-to-alter-html-head-using-hook-page-attachments-alter-per-node