# How can I add drupalSettings values with the #attached array?

Tags: javascript, 9

In D7, we have used drupal_add_js with DrupalSettings for accessing php variables to javascript files, for that we have used in D7 in my custom function like below

```
function custom_function($data)
{
   drupal_add_js(array('test_ajax_responders' => $data), 'setting');
}
```

But for D9, we need to use #attached property to replace this, but how i need to pass this $data related in to $attachments.
Seems this is my custom_function and $data is populating dynamically, so hard coding with page_attachments is not a feasible and that is used for different logic

So for this custom point of view how we can attach the drupalSetting variables in to existing $attachements array to get in javascript files.
I have tried below possibilities in D9 and nothing worked out.

```
function custom_function($data)
{
    return ['#attached' => ['drupalSettings' => [ 'test_ajax_responders' => $data, ],], ];
}

function custom_function($data) {
    $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['test_ajax_responders'] = $data;
    \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('page_attachments', $page);
}



libraries.yml file example

dependencies:        
- core/drupal
- core/jquery
- core/drupalSettings
```

Please help me to get my $data custom variable in to javascript files by using the above way.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Without knowing which hook/function/method is calling `custom_function()` we cannot tell you what the correct code should be and what `custom_function()` should return.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how dynamic the data is. Where do you get it from? Ideally you put it there. For example, attach the js data of a node in a preprocess hook. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288989/47547

If this is not possible attach it to  $attachments['#attached'] via [hook_page_attachments()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments) and declare the dynamic cache metadata in  $attachments['#cache']. However, this makes the page less cacheable. Depending on how dynamic the data is, consider loading it lazily via Ajax when the client is already running Ajax like in your case.