# How can I add CSS variables to the HTML head?

Tags: theming, 9

For my site I want to be able to set custom css variables to the sites head. I don't want to add css files just inline css code. In the end I want users to be able to set colors using a color picker. These colors should be translated to the css variables added to the sites head.

For this I looked at the code in the [css vars module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cssvars) this brought me a long way. But i'm not able to add css variables in the body of the page.

For this I use `hook_page_top`. But my code now is ending up in the top of the `<body>` and I want it to be in the `<head>`. Strange enough...when I look at the [screencast](https://vimeo.com/370081150) (min 7:35) of the creator of the css vars module I see that his code does get in to the `<head>`.

I simplified the code in my theme_color module to figure out how it works. So maybe that's the problem? How can I get my css variables in the head of the page?

I have a theme_color.module:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 *   CSS Variables module.
 */

use Drupal\theme_color\Hooks;

/**
 * Implements hook_page_top().
 */
function theme_color_page_top(array &$page_top) {
  Hooks::hookPageTop($page_top);
}
```

I have a Hooks.php just like the example module:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\theme_color;

class Hooks
{

  public static function hookPageTop(array &$pageTop)
  {
    if ($build = self::makeThemeColorBuild()) {
      $pageTop['theme_color'] = $build;
    }
  }

  private static function makeThemeColorBuild()
  {
    $build = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'style',
      '#value' => "html:root {\n--test-var: yellow;\n}",
    ];
    return $build;
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I tried earlier, and again after get the suggestions in comments to use `hook_preprocess_html`

```
function theme_color_preprocess_html(&$variables)
{
  $build = [
    '#tag' => 'style',
    '#value' => "html:root {\n--test-var: pink;\n}",
  ];
  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$build, '?tag?'];
}
```

This is working but what kind of tag do I need to put after the $build in the $variables line of code??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a meta tag in inside the <head> tag?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-inside-the-head-tag)

Comment: Implement `hook_preprocess_html` as in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: And doesn't this simply happen in your CSS like `:root { --primary-color: red; }`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with the last comment. Can you explain a bit more?

I'm trying to get the `hook_preprocess_html` to work but I think I'm missing something. I've edited the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this from `hook_preprocess_html` like in accepted answer to the duplicate question it works like in the snippet below.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $style = [
    '#tag' => 'style',
    '#value' => ":root {\n  --test-var: pink;\n}",
  ];
  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$style, 'foobar-my-id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for COLOR variables on Drupal. It uses the core color module and has a UI if you need it. https://www.drupal.org/project/css_color_variables